error MSB4057: The target "Learning05" does not exist in the project
I am having an issue when I click run it keeps saying
C:\Users\alyssa\Documents\CSE210\cse210-projects\csharp-prep\Prep1\Prep1.csproj : error MSB4057: The target "Prep1" does not exist in the project.
when the file is there, everything was working just fine befpre. If I type
dotnet run --project  C:\Users\alyssa\Documents\CSE210\cse210-projects\csharp-prep\Prep1\Prep1.csproj it runs in the terminal but if I click run on the right top corner it doesnt. what would be the issue?
everyting started when I had this method PauseWithAnimation(3); and when I changed to PauseWithAnimation(1); to have 1  second no project has worked since. can someone please help ?

Some more context would be appropriate. Maybe copy and pasting your code. Includeing your .csproj contents would be nice. I know this is dumb, but have you restarted your Visual Studio? And have you tried performing a Rebuild? Sometimes strange errors get resolved for me when I Rebuild/Restart

You really need to give us more information. Although, from your filenames, I did gather that you're using the code templates from here: https://github.com/byui-cse/cse210-ww-student-template

Hi @GabrielPierce I have restarted, I truied to restore, build, all of this. the problem is with my IDE, if I try to reate a new project and run any code I get the same error
I found this on chatgpt
Given that the project runs successfully using dotnet run --project but not when you click "Run" in the IDE, it indeed seems like a configuration issue within the IDE. Let's delve deeper into configuring Visual Studio and Visual Studio Code correctly.

@steliosbl isn't a problem with the code, even if I create a basic code it doesnt let em run. I get the same error, I dont know what happened with my vsc

@GabrielPierce I am in utah too

If it's an issue with your configuration, then you just need to Reset Your Settings
